# Tempo de transição não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dei 3 segundos para fazer uma transição mais sensível mas não funciona, está muito bruta:

```js
$(function(){
    var status = 0;

    /* INICIA MENU-GRID */
    $('.menu-grid').on('click',function(){
        console.log(status);

        if(status == 0) {
            $('aside').removeClass('inativo').addClass('ativo'),3000;
            status = 1;
        }else {
            $('aside').removeClass('ativo').addClass('inativo'),3000;
            status = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: É mais fácil fazer a transição no pelo CSS, na definição dessas classes. Sem esse `3000` no código (que não faz o que você acha).

Comment: eu tentei dar uma transition no css mas não funcionou

Answer (score 6):

É mais fácil resolver isso pelo CSS, na definição das suas classes. Por exemplo:

```js
$('div').addClass('off');
setTimeout( () => $('div').removeClass('off').addClass('on'), 3000);
```

```css
div { 
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
 }
.on { 
  background-color: green; 
 }
.off { 
  background-color: red; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Nota: essa sintaxe com `() =>` ainda tem alguns problemas de compatibilidade. O mais seguro seria isto:

```
setTimeout( function() { $('div').removeClass('off').addClass('on') }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso voce queira utilizar animacoes via jQuery, vc tera de usar o animate

```
 $( 'aside' ).animate({
     opacity: 0.25,
     left: "+=50",
   }, 3000, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
```

Vc pode utilizar tambem algo mais simples como o .toggle() ou o .toggleFade()

Animacoes devem ser feitas sempre que possivel via css, pois estas via JS acabam afetando drasticamente a performance da coisa.

O jQuery deve ser usado apenas para adicionar ou remover as classes dando-lhe o poder de escolher qual efeito e modificacao deve ser aplicada ao elemento.